# NSArrayController changes doesn't propagate to binded NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

**I have a master-detail GUI layout:**

1. `NSTableView` with content bound to an `NSArrayController`.
2. The `NSArrayController` data is bound to `NSUserDefaults` rows.
3. An `NSTextField` with value bound to the `NSArrayController`'s `selection` property.

The table is populated with data from the storage as it should, and selecting a row changes the textField value.

Editing the textfield changes the corresponding table row as it should, but it **does not change the `NSUserDefaults`**!

If I relaunch the app, the changes are not saved.
BTW, if I add/remove rows from the table - it is persisted, but changes to row data are not.

It seems like the changes in the `NSArrayController` `selection` dictionary are not propagated to `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: odd, I have a similar setup that uses a dictionary controller that works fine... does editing the table view directly update the user defaults?

Comment: what are the settings you have for the array controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What solved the problem finally was checking "Handles Content as Compound Value" in the content binding preferences of the ArrayController.

Screenshot:[image]

Comment: Do you know why? I had the same problem, and this was the solution. But the documentation is not clear...