# Changes in NSTableView do not update NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have:

1. An NSTableView populated with NSTableCellViews
2. Each NSTableCellView has a checkbox, image, and text
3. The NSTableView is bound to an NSArrayController
4. The NSArrayController's content array is bound to an array of dictionaries in NSUserDefaults

The NSTableView reads the NSUserDefaults array: showing the correct number of items and value for each checkbox, image, and text entry. However, clicking on the checkboxes does not change the values saved in NSUserDefaults so the whole table resets when I reopen my app.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301815/nsarraycontroller-changes-doesnt-propagate-to-binded-nsuserdefaults) raised the same issue, but their solution of checking "Handles Content as Compound Value" in the binding preferences of the Array Controller did not work for me.

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I think is happening:

The other answer had a text field that was bound directly the array controller. In a view-based table view using `NSTableCellView`, there's an extra level of indirection.

The elements of the array controller's content array get assigned to the table cell view's `objectValue`. Then, your checkbox is bound to the `objectValue` property of the table cell view. Suppose the elements are `NSMutableDictionary` objects. So, `objectValue` is an `NSMutableDictionary`. Toggling the checkbox changes one of the values in the dictionary. But that's not the same as calling `-setObjectValue:` on the table cell view. So, the table cell view's binding has no reason to forward the new object value through its binding to the array controller.

<strike>I *think* that setting "Handles Content As Compound Value" on the binding from the checkbox to the `NSTableCellView`'s `objectValue` will force it to call `-setObjectValue:` on the table cell view, which will then forward the new value through the binding to the array controller. This would be in addition to setting "Handles Content As Compound Value" on the array controller's binding to the user defaults controller.</strike>

I think you will need a custom subclass of `NSTableCellView` with a property for the checkbox. Bind the checkbox to this property instead of going through `objectValue`. The getter would obtain the relevant property (for this example, I'll use an `allowed` property) of the `objectValue`. The setter would actually modify the compound object and then assign it to the `objectValue` property to force the binding to write it back to the array controller. So, something like:

```
@property (getter=isAllowed, nonatomic) BOOL allowed;

...

- (BOOL) isAllowed
{
    MyModelClass* model = self.objectValue;
    return model.allowed;
}

- (void) setAllowed:(BOOL)allowed
{
    MyModelClass* model = self.objectValue;
    model.allowed = allowed;
    self.objectValue = model;
}

// Make sure KVO and bindings know that when objectValue changes that means that allowed changes, too.
+ (NSSet*) keyPathsForValuesAffectingAllowed
{
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"objectValue.allowed"];
}
```

Comment: There is not a "Handles Content As Compound Value" setting for the binding of the checkbox value to objectvalue.key. I believe only binding the Array Controller's content array provides that option.

Comment: Hmm. You're right. I think my analysis of the source of the problem still holds, but I have updated my answer to suggest a different solution.